# ServiceStack DateTime deserialization

Tags: c#, datetime, servicestack, deserialization

I have strange behavior when using JsonServiceClient

```
public class TestDto
{
    public DateTime Datetime { get; set; }
}

public class TestService : Service
{
    public void Get(TestDto dto)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dto.Datetime);
    }
}

JsConfig.DateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601;
JsConfig.AlwaysUseUtc = true;
JsConfig.AssumeUtc = true;

var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:8888/");

client.Get(new TestDto {Datetime = "2014-12-14T00:00:00.1100000Z".FromJson<DateTime>()});
client.Get(new TestDto {Datetime = "2014-12-14T00:00:00.1110000Z".FromJson<DateTime>()});
```

the results are

```
14.12.2014 3:00:00
14.12.2014 0:00:00
```

I'm using ServiceStack 4.0.36

Is that a bug?

Comment: It would help if you could work out where the problem is - for example, before you call `client.Get`, is the `TestDto` correct? If you hook this up to Fiddler or something similar, what's going across the wire?

Comment: Yes, before calling client.Get dto is correct.

Comment: And what's going across the wire? And do you have those config settings on the server side too?

Comment: Fiddler shows that first request is transformed into /json/reply/TestDto?datetime=2014-12-14T00:00:00.11Z

Comment: Right - which looks okay. So it's presumably the deserialization on the server...